# MySQL throwing error on second JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax-error, inner-join

I'm getting the following error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN product_catalog ON product_catalog.entity_id**

As a result of the following query:

```
SELECT sales_order.created_at , order_item.order_id, sales_order.increment_id, SUM(order_item.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered , COUNT( * ) 

FROM order_item

JOIN sales_order
ON sales_order.entity_id = order_item.order_id
WHERE sales_order.created_at > '2012-11-15 00:00:00'

JOIN product_catalog
ON product_catalog.entity_id = order_item.product_id
WHERE product_catalog.size = 14

GROUP BY order_item.order_id;
```

Variations on this query have worked for grouping different types of product by sales order in the past where I only needed to perform one `JOIN` to get all the info I needed. The problem I'm encountering is from the second `JOIN`. Clearly I'm missing something but I really am not sure what. :(

Comment: WHERE clause goes at the and of all JOIN condition.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it alright. I had no idea, clearly. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that `WHERE` condition must be after all `JOIN`

```
SELECT sales_order.created_at , order_item.order_id, sales_order.increment_id, SUM(order_item.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered , COUNT( * ) 

FROM order_item

JOIN sales_order
ON sales_order.entity_id = order_item.order_id

JOIN product_catalog
ON product_catalog.entity_id = order_item.product_id

WHERE product_catalog.size = 14
AND sales_order.created_at > '2012-11-15 00:00:00'
GROUP BY order_item.order_id;
```

First of all you have to `JOIN` your tables which you need. Then after `WHERE` clause come for conditions.

Comment: This solution worked like a charm. I had no idea about the position of the WHERE statements, which I suppose is predictable if you've only ever had to do a single JOIN. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

`JOIN...ON...` clause it's also section to input condition so you don't need `where` clause, just add `AND` instead.

```
SELECT sales_order.created_at , order_item.order_id, sales_order.increment_id, 
       SUM(order_item.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered , COUNT( * )     
FROM order_item    
JOIN sales_order ON sales_order.entity_id = order_item.order_id
                 and sales_order.created_at > '2012-11-15 00:00:00'
JOIN product_catalog ON product_catalog.entity_id = order_item.product_id
                     and product_catalog.size = 14
GROUP BY order_item.order_id;
```

Please consider below example I added aliases. It's good practice to use it because code is more readable.

```
SELECT SO.created_at , OI.order_id, SO.increment_id, 
       SUM(OI.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered , COUNT( * )     
FROM order_item  OI  
JOIN sales_order SO ON SO.entity_id = OI.order_id
                 and SO.created_at > '2012-11-15 00:00:00'
JOIN product_catalog PC ON PC.entity_id = OI.product_id
                     and PS.size = 14
GROUP BY OI.order_id;
```

Comment: I'm going to give this solution a try as well as an exercise in learning. :)

Comment: For me to improve your code it's good idea to keep conditions in `JOIN` section that concern. As your code from example with `WHERE` (unfortunately). Enjoy learning :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `WHERE` clauses are in the wrong spots.  See the code below for proper `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT sales_order.created_at, 
    order_item.order_id, 
    sales_order.increment_id, 
    SUM(order_item.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered, 
    COUNT( * )
FROM order_item
JOIN sales_order
    ON sales_order.entity_id = order_item.order_id
    AND sales_order.created_at > '2012-11-15 00:00:00'
JOIN product_catalog
    ON product_catalog.entity_id = order_item.product_id
    AND product_catalog.size = 14
GROUP BY order_item.order_id
```